# Mock a nested interface

Tags: moq

I want to test that a method is called on the inner interface, how would I do such a thing with moq? Given the following example, I expect Z.Joy() to invoke Ix.Method().

```
interface Ix { void Method(); }
interface Iy<T> {}
class Z {
    public Z (Iy<Ix> y) {}
    public void Joy() {}
}

[TestClass]
public class Test {
    [TestMethod]
    public void ATest() {
        var x = new Mock<Ix>();
        var y = new Moxk<Iy<Ix>>(); // how can I pass x.Object?
        var z = new Z(y.Object);

        x.Verify(() => x.Method());

        z.Joy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are mocking the interface `Iy<T>` you will have to place a expectation or setup on methods on that mocked interface that deal with `Ix`. I would expect you have something like this in `Iy<T>`.

```
interface Iy<T>
{
     T SomeMethod();
}
```

So here you can.

```
y.Setup(x => x.SomeMethod()).Returns(x.Object));
```

and somewhere in `z.Joy()` you will call `x.SomeMethod()`